# Serve React application with proxy, vercel.json works serve.json don't

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, vercel, serve

Got an application in React in production live on Vercel. with a custom proxy settings like this (vercel.json):

```json
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/api/:match*",
            "destination": "https://api.rentman.net/:match*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to run my own server and use npm serve to deploy my application and use the same rewrites settings (serve.json). But it does not work. Any ideas why not?